# Self-Invoking Functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

What's the difference between these functions? Thanks for reply!

**Function #1**

```
var myQuery = (function() {

  (...)

})();
```

**Function #2**

```
var myQuery = (function() {

  (...)

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case, you're self-invoking a function literal and assigning the value of the invocation to the variable `myQuery`.

In the second case, you're assigning a reference to the anonymous function that you've defined. Here, `myQuery` acts like a pointer or a reference to a function.

To better illustrate this.

```
var myQuery = (function() {
   return "Hello";
})();
```

In this case, `myQuery` contains the value `Hello`. Now if you had:

```
var myQuery = (function() {
   return "Hello";
});
```

`myQuery` contains a reference to the function. If you used `console.log` in Firebug to output this value, you would see `function()`. This reference is something you can pass around or even invoke. So:

```
var myQuery = (function() {
   return "Hello";
});

var value = myQuery();
```

Now, `value` will contain `Hello`. Hope this explains the difference.

Comment: @Randy: Also notice that in the second case you don't need the surrounding parentheses, so `var myQuery = function() { … };` will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

I'll simplify `Function #2` and perhaps that will better show the differences.

```
var myQuery = function(){ (...) };
```

In Function #2, you're saying "Assign myQuery a reference to this function."
In Function #1, you're saying "Assign myQuery the value of a call to this function."

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a self-invoking function, called with an empty parameter list. The value of myQuery will be what this function returns.

The second one is simple assignment of an anonymous function. There is no invocation in this one.

Answer (score 0):

well the first function executes as the line is passed and the second will have to be executed to get the value

Eg : http://jsfiddle.net/yVrwX/